# Saving the content of recycler view after user has made changes onto it and generate a new list of object

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-recyclerview

[This is how my viewHolder looks like. It has the spinner element. I have called the getItemCount() method using adapter to get the size of the list that is populated on recycler view. Now User can select an item from the spinner. After user has made all the changes i.e. by changing the spinners in all the views needed, i want to retrieve the changed position of spinners for all the viewholders in a array list.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HP8vj.png) I am working on android recyclerview. There is a list of objects that is passed to the adapter and the list is displayed perfectly. Each of my viewholder have three views in it. These are two text views and one spinner. User can select one of the options available from the spinner and that's how my recyclerview will be updated.
I need help for saving the updated list of object i.e., the spinner position selected by the user for all the list items to generate an xml out of it.

my code looks like this:

```
    int size = mAdapter.getItemCount();
    int val[]= new int[size]; //till here it's working perfectly fine

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        View view_temporary = recyclerView.getChildAt(i);
        Spinner spin = (Spinner)view_temporary.findViewById(R.id.action);
        val[i] = spin.getSelectedItemPosition();
        Log.d("OfficeSpace", ""+val[i]);
    }
```

//here activity crashes

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! In order to get more help with this, can you share your code or at least what you have tried to do already?

Comment: @BrandonHaugen I have updated the post, please see if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. I wanted to save the status of my spinner item present in my view holder after scrolling back to the top. Inside my onBind method of recyclerView, i added this code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Features feature = mFeatures.get(position); //to get the current object from the list

    holder.mSpinner.setSelection(feature.getVal());

    holder.mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            mFeatures.get(position).setVal(pos);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

}
```